# Need to extract a pdf in to excel

Tags: python

I need to extract a pdf into Excel. I am able to extract all the columns except `sku description` from the image below:

[image: table]

The code that I have so far:

```
input_path = ""


pdfFileObj = open(input_path,'rb')

df1 = tabula.read_pdf(input_path, stream=True)
pdfFileObj = open(input_path,'rb')
df1= tabula.read_pdf(input_path, stream = True, pages = "all")
df1.to_excel("{0}.xlsx".format(input_path),index=False)
```

I can get all the columns except `sku description`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Camelot which has given better results for tabular data.

```
pip install camelot-py
```

Comment: I am not able install Camelot i tried , as a prerequisite it is asking to install ghost script i installed even that  but no luck.